# How to use ? and * in Angular routing

Tags: angularjs

I need to define a path in AngularJS routing to:

1. have an optional parameter
2. have it accepting values of a relative path

Some examples for the parameter values are:

```
/ABC
/ABC/123
/ABC/123/XYZ
```

I have tried

```
'/Documents/:folderUrl*'
```

which takes care of the `/` character in the parameter value but if the parameter is empty, it goes to .otherwise().

```
'/Documents/:folderUrl?'
```

makes it optional but cannot let me have `/ABC/123` as a value because of the `/` character.

I prefer not to have two .when() as I have doubts it loads the controller two times, which is an issue I have explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371962/routing-loads-controller-two-times?noredirect=1#comment45084697_28371962).

Comment: I don't understand "does not allow me to have it empty.". What do you want to be empty?

Comment: Goes to .otherwise()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite difficult to pass encoded slashes in urls as the browser will change it to a slash. The only solution I came up with is to double encode the slashes. I used [this encoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) to do the encoding but it could be done in your angular app if needed using `encodeURIComponent`. That means the url is instead `#/Documents/ABC%252F123`.

To setup the parameter you first have to add it to the routing config in `app.js`. I've added the parameter called `url` and made it optional with the `?` symbol:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/Documents/:url?', {
        templateUrl: 'view.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/Documents/'
      });
});
```

Then in your controller you can use `$routeParams` to get the url. But since the slashes are double encoded you need to use `decodeURIComponent` to decode the url:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.url = decodeURIComponent($routeParams.url);
})
```

Click the `a` link in the demo to see the url being passed.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/s9mtsdY9kxBhyNjxk94n?p=preview)